# Upper Bound on Aliquot Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, divisor-sum, upper-lower-bounds

Let $s_1(n)=\big{(}\sum_{d|n}d\big{)}-n=\sigma_1(n)-n$ be the restricted divisor sum, and define $s_k(n)=s_1(s_{k-1}(n))$ as the $k^{th}$ term of the [aliquot sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AliquotSequence.html) starting at $n$. What is the best proven upper bound on $s_k(n)$? In other words, if the sequence starting at $n$ seems to tend to infinity, how fast does it do so? [Existing bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate) on $\sigma(n)$ might help...
Alternatively, is it possible to bound $\sum_{n\leq x}s_k(n)$?

Comment: Is there any reason to assume the bound for $s(s(s(\ldots(n))$ will be much smaller than $f(f(f(\ldots(n)))) $ where  $f(n) = \sup_{m \le n} s(m)$ ? Maybe in mean value, adding some noise to $s(n)$, letting us use $\sum_{n \le x} s(n) \sim \frac{\zeta(2)-1}{2} x^2 $ ?

Comment: @user1952009 how exactly would that work? I don't see how you would extend $\sum_{n\leq x} s(n)$ to $s^k(n)$...

Comment: There are several authors that studied the problem of aliquot sequences. Just as companion of Gerry Myerson answer, you could be interested (it isn't directly related to your question but the definition in this paper are very important) in K. Guy and Selfridge, *What Drives an Aliquot Sequence*, Mathematics of Computation, Vol 29 No. 129 (1975). Additonally you've [Juan L. Varona WWW page about aliquot sequences](http://www.unirioja.es/cu/jvarona/aliquot.html). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erdos, On asymptotic properties of aliquot sequences, Math Comp 30 (1976), no. 135, 641-645, MR0404115 (53 #7919), proved that for every fixed $k$ and every $\delta>0$ and for all $n$ except a sequence of density zero one has $$(1-\delta)n(s(n)/n)^i<s_i(n)<(1+\delta)n(s(n)/n)^i$$ for $1\le i\le k$.